# Use variable inside a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to add some DOM when click in a button. But i want to add the name attribute dynamically. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                console.log("done");
                var counterEdu = 1;
                $("#add-edu").click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    counterEdu  = counterEdu+1;    
                    $("#passing-year").after('<div class="col-md-12 form-group1">'+'<input type="text" placeholder="Degree Name" name="degree"+counterEdu;>'

                });
            });
```

I want to add the name attribute concatenated with

> counterEdu

variable. like degree1,degree2.....
so how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape it properly:

```
$("#passing-year").after('<div class="col-md-12 form-group1">' + '<input type="text" placeholder="Degree Name" name="degree'+counterEdu +'">'
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. :)

Comment: @MutasimFuad, you're welcome. I'm glad it worked. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since counterEdu is not a string

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("done");
            var counterEdu = 1;
            $("#add-edu").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                counterEdu  = counterEdu+1;    
                $("#passing-year").after('<div class="col-md-12 form-group1">'+'<input type="text" placeholder="Degree Name" name="degree'+counterEdu+'">'

            });
        });
```

Comment: This is not ok. Hint: `name` attribute is closing earlier.